# Undefined symbol: _ZN7QString13toUtf8_helperERKS_ at runtime

Tags: c++, eclipse, qt, gcc

I have two projects using Qt. One is being developed with QtCreator, the other with eclipse. Both use the same Qt 5.3.1 libraries, both are compiled with GCC. However, when I run the program that is in eclipse, it crashes with the message `Undefined symbol: _ZN7QString13toUtf8_helperERKS_`.

A lookup showed that the code producing this error is

```
path.toStdString().c_str()     // path is a QString
```

and the exact location within qstring.h is

```
#if defined(Q_COMPILER_REF_QUALIFIERS) && !defined(QT_COMPILING_QSTRING_COMPAT_CPP)
    QByteArray toLatin1() const & Q_REQUIRED_RESULT
    { return toLatin1_helper(*this); }
    QByteArray toLatin1() && Q_REQUIRED_RESULT
    { return toLatin1_helper_inplace(*this); }
    QByteArray toUtf8() const & Q_REQUIRED_RESULT
    { return toUtf8_helper(*this); } //                 <- here
    QByteArray toUtf8() && Q_REQUIRED_RESULT
    { return toUtf8_helper(*this); }
    QByteArray toLocal8Bit() const & Q_REQUIRED_RESULT
    { return toLocal8Bit_helper(constData(), size()); }
    QByteArray toLocal8Bit() && Q_REQUIRED_RESULT
    { return toLocal8Bit_helper(constData(), size()); }
```

Converting a `QString` to `std::string` in the other project (the one in QtCreator) works just fine. What might be the problem? Are there any compiler options missing in eclipse?

**Edit:**
The compiler outputs for sample files from the two projects are (I added line breaks for readability):

Eclipse

```
Building file: ../src/mysource1.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -I"/home/username/myfolder/myproject1/src"
    -I"/home/username/myfolder/myproject1/src/dialogs"
    -I"/home/username/myfolder/myproject1/src/ignore"
    -I/usr/local/Qt-5.3.1/include -I/usr/local/Qt-5.3.1/include/QtCore
    -I/usr/local/Qt-5.3.1/include/QtGui -I/usr/local/Qt-5.3.1/include/QtWidgets
    -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++0x -fPIE -MMD -MP
    -MF"src/mysource1.d" -MT"src/mysource1.d" -o "src/mysource1.o"
    "../src/mysource1.cpp"
```

QtCreator

```
g++ -c -pipe -g -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIE -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB
    -DQT_CORE_LIB -I/usr/local/Qt-5.3.1/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I../myproject2 
    -I../myproject2/src -I../myproject2/src/data -I../myproject2/src/dialogs 
    -I../myproject2/src/widgets -I../myproject2/src/widgets/overlays
    -I../myproject2/src/widgets/tools -I/usr/local/Qt-5.3.1/include
    -I/usr/local/Qt-5.3.1/include/QtWidgets -I/usr/local/Qt-5.3.1/include/QtGui
    -I/usr/local/Qt-5.3.1/include/QtCore -I. -I. -o mainwind.o
    ../myproject2/src/mainwind.cpp
```

**Edit2:**
The linker outputs are as follows:

Eclipse

```
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++ -L/usr/local/Qt-5.3.1/lib -o "myproject1" /*list of .o files*/
    -lQt5Core -lQt5Gui -lQt5Widgets -lgit2
```

QtCreator

```
g++ -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/Qt-5.3.1/lib -o myproject2 /*list of .o files*/
    -L/usr/local/Qt-5.3.1/lib -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lGL -lpthread
```

Comment: I'm not sure so I will write a comment instead of answer. Undefined symbol error raises when source file with these symbols is not included in compiled sources.

Comment: @fnc12 I'm not sure I understood correctly: The symbol for `QString::toUtfHelper` is present in the source header, but not in the compiled library? But I'm using the source files that were copied by `make install` to `/usr/local/Qt-5.3.1`, and the libraries that are in the same folder (I checked it with `ldd`). How can there be an inconsistency here? And besides, the other project uses the same files without errors.

Comment: using Qt a static library or as dynamic ?

Comment: Just a random try  - Qt is built with a set of pre processor definitions ( whether you built or pre built ). If the same set of pre processor definitions aren't used in QtCreator/Eclipse, then that will mean that the Qt header file included in Eclipse, is slightly different ( assume any function declaration is guarded with preprocessor ). That affects vtables pointers. Can you make sure the same pre processors definitions is used in Eclipse and QtCreator. Hope you could confirm from build messages.

Comment: @Kiran How do I view preprocessor definitions in QtCreator? I have none listed in eclipse. However, QtCreator uses qmake, maybe qmake has some built-in preprocessor settings of some kind?

Comment: Can u add -D flags present in qt creator command line to eclipse gcc command - I mean -D_REENTRANT -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB

Comment: @Kiran Thanks for the suggestion, I tried, but nothing changed.

Comment: `QString::toUtf8_helper(QString const&)` demangled (courtesy `c++filt -t`)

Comment: I really hope you have setup Eclipse to invoke `cmake` before `g++`.

Comment: @AntonPoznyakovskiy `qMake/Cmake` is the way to go. But it is interesting to see how come linker succeeds and then during run, we get undefined reference( not different dll case ). There is no preprocessor guard for `toUtf8_helper` in QT(https://github.com/qtproject/qtbase/blob/v5.3.1/src/corelib/tools/qstring.cpp#L4337). One more try. Can you add -DQT_COMPILING_QSTRING_COMPAT_CPP so that https://github.com/qtproject/qtbase/blob/5.3.1/src/corelib/tools/qstring.h#L464 is not executed and we take slightly different path with the `toUtf8()` in #else part.

Comment: @Kiran Adding -DQT_COMPILING_QSTRING_COMPAT_CP solved it. Thanks a lot, post it as an answer, please.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`qmake/cmake` is the way to go. But it is interesting to see how come linker succeeds and then during run, we get an undefined reference( not an unmatched dll case ). Especially since there is no preprocessor guard for `toUtf8_helper` in QT [github repo](https://github.com/qtproject/qtbase/blob/v5.3.1/src/corelib/tools/qstring.cpp#L4337). One more try. Can you add `-DQT_COMPILING_QSTRING_COMPAT_CPP` so that, we take slightly different path with the `toUtf8()` in [#else](https://github.com/qtproject/qtbase/blob/5.3.1/src/corelib/tools/qstring.h#L464) part and not invoke the missing `toUtf8_helper` method.

**Cause:** I assume this happened since QtCore dll got built with a set of preprocessor flags which was not matched during the build of your project. Then the header files like `qstring.h` included in your code, which has inline functions, guarded with preprocessor definitions, as in for `toUtf8()` which is called during `toStdString()` will take a different path.

Also note that trying to build QT project with out `qmake/cmake` files as in this question/answer is not advised, and is bound to cause more problems in projects.

Comment: In my case, it was `-DQT_COMPILING_QSTRING_COMPAT_CPP` - just in case anybody else stumbles upon this.

Comment: Using -DQT_COMPILING_QSTRING_COMPAT_CPP fixxed the problem in my case too. Thank you very much for sharing this information, kind SIr!

Answer (score 2):

`Undefined symbol: _ZN7QString13toUtf8_helperERKS_` is likely caused by:

Linking in eclipse is made to wrong (outdated Qt libraries) due to missing `-Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/Qt-5.3.1/lib` or `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Eclipse build environment is not setup as the QtCreator build environment.

**You write you have checked dynamic linking of your app using `ldd` but you should add missing linker option `-Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/Qt-5.3.1/lib`in eclipse as well.**

(Another alternative would be to use LD_LIBRARY_PATH, but it is sound to keep both build environments equal. ldd is influenced by LD_LIBRARY_PATH as is the app. LD_LIBRARY_PATH might not be exported correctly?)

Also add compiler flags `-D_REENTRANT -fPIE -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB
    -DQT_CORE_LIB -I/usr/local/Qt-5.3.1/mkspecs/linux-g++`

Answer (score 0):

I assume You want to convert `QString` to `const char *` using QString.toStdString().c_str() function. This is not a reliable method to do it. I don't know what documents say, but I tried getting file location using this function and it gave me something weird. Please check if const char* has same value as you have in QString. If this is the case, then you have two options.

1. either do this in two steps. i.e. `QString().toStdString()` and
   in next step convert it into `const char*`. Although it is not
   clean, but it works. (main problem is to have 'deep copy'. When you
   convert QString to std::string, Qt create a temp object and directly
   tries to read this temp object.With this method, you will create two
   separate objects.
2. Use `QString().toAscii.constData()` or `QString():toUtf8().constData()` (preferable)

Comment: While you are right that `QString::toUtf8().constData()` is more elegant way to convert `QString` to `const char *`, it still produces this error, as well as your other suggestions. It is the conversion from QString to Utf8 that seems to be problematic, and it is also used in the conversion to `std::string`. Btw, QString::toAscii() doesn't exist anymore as of Qt5.

Comment: Did you implement it in two different steps? Like qstring to stdstring and from stdstring to const char*? If so, when does it crash?

Comment: Yes, `std::string spath = path.toStdString();` and it crashes on conversion to `std::string`.

Comment: The string you are trying convert, is it in English??

Comment: It's a path within the file system. I just checked it, it has no non-Ascii characters.

Comment: I checked qstring 5.4 manual. I think you should use qstring().toLocal8bit().constData() function. Try and tell.

Comment: Thank you, but nope. The error is thrown at the same location, but now the undefined symbol is `_ZN7QString18toLocal8Bit_helperEPK5QChari`

Comment: Isn't there still qPrintable(). Edit yes: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qPrintable

Comment: It may sound ridiculous, but clean all, run qmake, build all might work.

Comment: I don't use qmake for this project, just gcc.

Comment: Are you running that program from the command line, or from Eclipse?

Comment: @HappyCactus I tried both, with the same result. I'll double-check later this day whether the error message is the same when I run from command line, but as far sa I remember it was the same.

Comment: @user21071987 Your problems with `toStdString().c_str()` were probably due to the fact that you did not pay attention to the intermediary `std::string` destruction. e.g. this will not work `return a.toStdString().c_str()`, while this will work `myFunc(a.toStdString().c_str())`

Comment: @HappyCactus No actually I can run the program from the command line, and the main window opens up, but then I get a list of strange `QObject::connect: signal not found in QAction` errors, and none of my defined signals seem to work.

Comment: @AntonPoznyakovskiy I think you need to check for all dependency now. Try "Hello World" and check if everything is working, and then think ahead.

Comment: @AndréPuel, I completely agree with you. I think I was not elaborate enough technically, but i mean same thing. I said temp object of std::string which goes out of the scope if you assign it to something. In stupid term, if you try use it after ';' it will not work but if you use this before ';' it will work. Therefore `const char * var = str.toUtf8().constData;` will not work, but `doSomething(str.toUtf8().constData);` will work.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, you're not having a compile error but a linking one. You haven't showed us the *linking* command that is being used, you should check if they're different. To use `QString` methods properly you have to link against QtCore.

Which build system are you using? Care to try from the command line? What if you compile it by yourself? I read some of your comments, you seemed to have checked the executables with `ldd`, is the output of both of them the same?

Also, these flags: `-DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB`, they probably make a difference, you should try to have these defined in the Eclipse project too.

Qt's libraries can be complex to be used bare-handed without a proper build system (e.g, you're missing proper defines in your Eclipse project), specially if you intend to use QtQuick or if you intend to build to Android in the future. I'd go with *qmake* or *CMake*. If your plan is to support different IDEs, *CMake* is worth it as it can generate projects for most of them.

Comment: I added linker outputs to the question. In Eclipse, I am using the Linux GCC toolchain with Gnu Make Builder. The output of `ldd` is the same as far as it concerns Qt, the executables are linked to exactly the same files `/usr/local/Qt-5.3.1/lib/libQt5Core.so.5`, `/usr/local/Qt-5.3.1/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5` and `/usr/local/Qt-5.3.1/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5`. However, in the output of the QtCreator project, these are listed in reverse order, not sure if that could play a role. What do you mean by trying from command line and compiling myself, running gcc manually instead of from an IDE?